# Laravel 4: Where Not Exists

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I need my model to return only those records from one table where a matching record does not exist in another table. I was thinking that the solution might be with [Query Scopes](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes) but the documentation only scratches the surface. So my SQL would look something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT A_id FROM B
                WHERE B.A_id = A.id)
```

Here are my tables:

```
A
-------------
| id | name |
-------------

B
--------------------
| id | A_id | name |
--------------------
```

Probably unnecessary but here are my models. Model for A:

```
class A extends Eloquent{

    public function B(){
        return $this->hasOne('B', 'A_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Model for B:

```
class B extends Eloquent{

    public function A(){
        return $this->belongsTo('B', 'A_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Something like

```
A::whereNotExists(function($query)
            {
                $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                      ->from('B')
                      ->whereRaw('A.id = B.id');
            })
            ->get();
```

Comment: I need the opposite of the has method. (Is there a `hasNot()` method?)

Comment: I did find the `whereNotExists` method and I'm working with that now. But I'm finding a problem: In the `whereRaw` I have to use the entire table name (prefix and all) I'd don't want my prefix to be found anywhere in my code.

Comment: Also, I'm guessing that your code above should be in the Controller. Is there a way to do it in the Model?

Comment: You can put it in a query scope method containing: return static::whereNotExists(function($query)
            {
                $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                      ->from('B')
                      ->whereRaw('A.id = B.id');
            })
            ->get();

Comment: Thanks @marcanuy. Giving that a try now. Do I really have to use the full table name (with prefix) in the `whereRaw`?

Comment: AFAIK yes but you can get the model current table name with the **table** property of each Eloquent model so it is not hardcoded

Comment: Thanks @marcanuy. Actually simply removing the table names from the whereRaw worked fine for my Controller. So here's my code: `$records = DB::table('A') ->whereNotExists(function($query){$query ->select(DB::raw('A_id')) ->from('B') ->whereRaw('A_id = id');}) ->get();` Still trying to get it to work in my Model.

Comment: I'm trying to get this working in my model as you suggested. It works fine if I explicitly refer to my table in the `whereRaw` this way: `whereRaw('A_id = pre_A.id')` (where `pre` is my prefix). But when I try and pull in the `table` property as you suggest I get an error. I tried it this way: `whereRaw('A_id = '. $this->table .'.id')`. This pulls in the name of the table without the prefix. I've defined the table in my model this way: `protected $table = 'A';`

Comment: Sorry I have misunderstood the prefix issue, I though you were referring to using the table name explicitly in the query. To use the database prefix defined in your database config use: DB::getTablePrefix(); so you can just preppend it to the query.

Comment: This worked: `scopeName($query){return $query->whereNotExists(function($query){$this_table = DB::getTablePrefix() . $this->table;  $query->select(DB::raw('A_id'))  ->from('B')   ->whereRaw('A_id = '.$this_table.'.id');  })}` Thank you

Comment: Can you see the related question please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42458971/how-to-rewrite-sql-query-in-laravel