# Eloquent query results limited by relation criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables, affiliates and meetings and I want to build Eloquent query which will list all affiliates without those who have appointed meeting at specified date and time. So, the result should contain all affiliates who don't have any meeting and also those with meetings but not on specified date and time.

Users: id, name, city...

Meetings: id, client, date, time, user_id...

Can it be done without joins or raw sql (whereRaw or DB::raw) and how?

Test data users:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:5 [▼
    "id" => 2
    "name" => "John"
    "city" => "New York"
    "created_at" => "2015-02-19 00:26:43"
    "updated_at" => "2015-02-19 00:34:03"
  ]
  1 => array:5 [▼
    "id" => 3
    "name" => "Elisabeth"
    "city" => "Kansas City"
    "created_at" => "2015-02-19 00:26:43"
    "updated_at" => "2015-02-19 00:26:43"
  ]
  2 => array:5 [▼
    "id" => 4
    "name" => "Teodora"
    "city" => "New York"
    "created_at" => "-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
    "updated_at" => "-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
  ]
]
```

Test data meetings:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:8 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "client" => "George P."
    "date" => "2015-05-15"
    "time" => "14:00:00"
    "approved" => 1
    "user_id" => 2
    "created_at" => "2015-02-19 00:26:43"
    "updated_at" => "2015-02-19 00:26:43"
  ]
  1 => array:8 [▼
    "id" => 2
    "client" => "Jack White"
    "date" => "2015-05-15"
    "time" => "12:00:00"
    "approved" => 1
    "user_id" => 2
    "created_at" => "2015-02-19 00:26:43"
    "updated_at" => "2015-02-19 00:26:43"
  ]
  2 => array:8 [▼
    "id" => 3
    "client" => "Philip B."
    "date" => "2015-05-16"
    "time" => "16:00:00"
    "approved" => 1
    "user_id" => 3
    "created_at" => "2015-02-19 00:26:43"
    "updated_at" => "2015-02-19 00:26:43"
  ]
]
```

Expected result all users who don't have meeting on 2015-05-15 at 12:00

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:5 [▼
    "id" => 3
    "name" => "Elisabeth"
    "city" => "Kansas City"
    "created_at" => "2015-02-19 00:26:43"
    "updated_at" => "2015-02-19 00:26:43"
  ]
  1 => array:5 [▼
    "id" => 4
    "name" => "Teodora"
    "city" => "New York"
    "created_at" => "-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
    "updated_at" => "-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
  ]
]
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Without joins yes. What do you mean by raw sql ?

Comment: How? (: I meant whereRaw or DB::raw

Comment: Can you add the test data and the expected output to the question ?

Comment: Basically you mean Model::whereNotExists() ? Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22409469/laravel-4-where-not-exists ?

Comment: Won't that just exclude all users who were appointed to a meeting regardless of when it takes place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your user model has a relation `meetings` you can do this:

```
$users = User::whereDoesntHave('meetings', function($q){
    $q->where('time', '12:00:00');
})->get();
```