# How to rewrite SQL query in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I use the following Query Builder:

```
$res = Announcement::whereExists(function ($query) {
                $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                    ->from('announcement_category')
                    ->join('user_category', 'user_category.category_id', '=', 'announcement_category.category_id')
                    ->where('user_category.user_id', 1)
                    ->where('announcement_category.announcement_id', '=', 'announcements.id')
                    ->whereNull('deleted_at');
            })->get();
```

How to rewrite this query using short form `with`:

```
Announcement::with("announcement_category")...
```

Because, in this query builders adds conditon and `where delete_at NOT null` in the end, and it works wrong.

Relations between tables:

```
Announcement           Announcement_category          User_category
_____________          ____________________________   _______________
id | name             announcement_id | category_id   user_id | category_id
```

1) `Announcement` can has one or more categories `(Announcement has many Announcement_category)`

2) User can has one or more categories

3) `User_category` is related with `Announcement_category` by `category_id = category_id`

Comment: Can you show the relationships you have set up between `Announcement`, `AnnouncementCategory` and `User`?

Comment: Yes, look updated question

Comment: Try reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23153678/eloquent-with-nested-wherehas

Comment: 1) Which table does the `delete_at` belong to? 2) Shouldn't it be `deleted_at` if you're using SoftDeletes? 3) Do you have the relationships set up in your model e.g. `Announcement` belongsToMany `Category` and `Category` belongsToMany `User`?

Comment: `deleted_at` only in `Announcement` table, and it NULL if not deleted. I dont have relationships in model, because I dont aware what type of relation between `AnnouncementCategory` and `UserCategory`. No, Announcement can has many Category and it has no relations with User. User has only relation with `UserCategory` `by field: user.id = user_category.user_id`

Comment: Can you go to chat?

Comment: The relationships you would need are No.3 from my previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define the relationship between Announcement and AnnouncementCategory first

```
public function announcement_category() {
 return $this->hasMany(AnnouncementCategory::class, 'announcement_id')
}
```

Then, add condition to the relationship as you go or even set it up in the relationship function.

Comment: And how yo use this(call)? Can you share full example?

Comment: Like this? `Announcement::with("announcement_category")->where("user_id", 1)`